# Recurse through Map

Tags: scala, recursion, dictionary

How can I recurse through a Map?

I'm looking for something similar to list recursion, shown below.

```
def count(list: List[Int]): Int = { 
   def go(list: List[Int], acc: Int)) = {
      case x :: xs => go(xs, x + sum)
      case Nil => sum
   }
   go(list, 0)
}
```

Please ignore the fact that `fold` or `reduce` could be used here. I'm mentioning this tail-recursive function as a sample as to what I'd like for recursing through a map. I want to be able to append to an `accumulator` argument when recursing through a map.

Comment: You can call `.toList` on your map, yielding a list of (key, value) Pairs, then recursing through the list. Convert back to a map at the end.

Comment: Map.keys() is an Iterable, so you can use it in the same way you use your `list` parameter.

Comment: I'd recommend calling `.toStream` on the map since Streams are lazy. That way you don't have the overhead of creating a whole list up-front, especially if you're not going to traverse the whole thing in  your recursive function.

Comment: fold is actually usually quite good when you want to use an accumulator.  can you explain more why fold doesn't fit your use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the Map into a Seq with .toSeq or .toList or similar, or you can define your own Map extractor, but the easiest is to just use head and tail directly.

```
def recursive[A, B](map: Map[A, B]): Int = 
  if (map.isEmpty) 0 else helper(map)

def helper[A, B](map: Map[A, B]): Int = (map.head, map.tail) match {
  case ((a, b), xs) if xs.isEmpty => 1
  case ((a, b), xs) => 1 + helper(xs)
}
```